# Getting the x/y position of an XSSFChart (xlsx chart) with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, openxml

If I have an XSSFChart (or an XSSFDrawing, which contains charts), how do I get the x/y position of that chart on the sheet?  It seems like this should be an easy thing to do, but I have not been able to figure it out.

Comment: Share with us... what you have tried?

Comment: Well, a bunch of things that didn't work... I tried getting the CTChart object and getting the position from the XML, but it wasn't there, I tried getting the anchor of the frame with getGraphicFrame().getAnchor(), but that returned null... It seems to me that something like this should be a simple method call or two, not a process, and it either works or it doesn't.